# Can SpecWatchr integrate with dotCover?

Tags: code-coverage, bdd, nspec

Can the NSpec [SpecWatchr](http://nspec.org/continuoustesting/) tool integrate with [dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) to analyze code coverage by tests?

Answer (score 0):

SpecWatchr is simply a file watcher that executes rake tasks in a Rakefile.  Using DebuggerShim.cs (decorated with NUnit's TestFixture attribute), you should be able to create a rake task that will run that specific test through dotCover.

Link to DebuggerShim.cs:
https://github.com/mattflo/NSpec/blob/master/NSpecSpecs/DebuggerShim.cs

And then you can change SpecWatchr to run dotCover if DebuggerShim.cs is changed:
https://github.com/amirrajan/SpecWatchr/blob/master/dotnet.watchr.rb#L223

Rake file execution in SpecWatchr:
https://github.com/amirrajan/SpecWatchr/blob/master/dotnet.watchr.rb#L177

Feel free to reach out to me on twitter, I'd be happy to set up a Skype session to walk you through it.